# React authentication HoC

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, redux-saga

I have a React-Router-Redux application that I built with an expressJS server. Part of this application is authentication using JWT. Aside from protecting Routes, I am trying to create a HoC that will protect it's wrapped component by reaching out to the server and authenticating before displaying the wrapped component. Here is the HoC I have built:

withAuth.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../../store/actions';

export default function (ComposedComponent) {
  class Authenticate extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
      console.log('will mount');
      this.props.authenticate();
    }

    render() {
      const { loading, loaded } = this.props;
      return !loading && loaded ? <ComposedComponent {...this.props} /> : null;
    }
  }

  const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
      loading: state.auth.loading,
      loaded: state.auth.loaded
    };
  };

  const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
      authenticate: () => dispatch(actions.authenticate())
    };
  };

  return connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Authenticate)
}
```

I am using Redux Saga aswell. The authenticate action calls a saga that sets loading to true, loaded to false and reaches out to the server. When the server sends confirmation, loaded is set to true and loading is set to false, aside from a cookie and some data being saved.

It basically works, but the problem is that when I enter a route with this HoC, the authentication process is done twice (HoC's ComponentWillMount is called twice) and I cant figure out why. It happens with a wrapped component that doesnt even reach out to the server or change props on mount/update. What am I missing here?

This is one of the wrapped components that has this problem:

```
class SealantCustomer extends Component {
  state = {
    controls: {
      ...someControls
    }
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    if (JSON.stringify(this.props.sealantCustomer) === JSON.stringify(nextProps.sealantCustomer)) return false;
    else return true;
  }

  updateInput = (event, controlName) => {
    let updatedControls = inputChangedHandler(event, controlName, this.state.controls);
    this.setState({controls: updatedControls});
  }

  searchCustomer = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.fetchCustomer(this.state.controls.phone.value, this.state.controls.site.value, this.state.controls.name.value);
  }

  render () {

    let sealantCustomer;

    if (this.props.loading) {
      sealantCustomer = <Loader />;
    }

    if (!this.props.loading) {
      if (!this.props.sealantCustomer) this.props.error ? sealantCustomer = <h3 style={{color: 'salmon'}}>ERROR: {this.props.error}</h3> : sealantCustomer = <h3>Please search for a sealant customer</h3>
      else if (this.props.sealantCustomer.length === 0) sealantCustomer = <h3>Found no sealant customers with these details!</h3>
      else {
        let data = [];
        this.props.sealantCustomer.forEach(person => {
          ...filling data here
        })

        const columns = [{
          ...table columns
        }]
        const keysToSkip = [keys];

        sealantCustomer = <ReactTable data={data} columns={columns} defaultPageSize={3} className={['-striped', '-highlight', 'tableDefaults'].join(" ")} 
          SubComponent={sub component} />
      }
    }
    return (
      <div className={classes.sealantCustomerPage}>
        <SearchBox controls={this.state.controls} submit={this.searchCustomer} inputUpdate={this.updateInput} name="Sealant Customers" />
        <div className={classes.sealantCustomer}>
          {sealantCustomer}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    loading: state.searches.loading,
    error: state.searches.error,
    sealantCustomer: state.searches.sealantCustomer
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    fetchCustomer: (phone, site, name) => dispatch(actions.searchSealantCustomer(phone, site, name))
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SealantCustomer);
```

Comment: You should call async functions at componentDidMount, not at componentWillMount

Comment: I'll give it a try. Could you please explain why though?

Comment: You wait the component to mount to do it. This avoids double mouting. It should happen once. React docs says you should perform remote api calls there https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount . Let me know if it works and I’ll write a proper answer for the question

Comment: I changed to DidMount and it still mounts twice